# Alternatives to Offline Editing Plugin of QGIS?

Tags: postgis, wfs, editing, software-recommendations, offline

I am looking for a way to edit my postgis layers offline (in field) using a Microsft Surface Tablet.

I have been testing the "Offline Editing Plugin" unsuccessfully. These are the issues I have experienced:

- It does not work with WFS layers. When I try to convert the layer to offline QGIS crashes.
- It does not work with MULTIGEOMETRIES
- I get some warnings saying that it does not understand QDate fields (normal date fields in postgis).

Despite all these issues, I tried to use the plugin with a layer loaded directly from postgis and with a single geometries (No MULTIGEOMETRY). It turns the database offline Ok, I edit some features, but when I click on Sync data, the data is not updated in the database. Nothing happens in the database.

Due to this, I have discarded to use this plugin. Do you know any other software, architecture or whatever that could have a similar functionality, but working?

Comment: For focussed Q&A you could ask about what you have tried and where you are stuck for one of your three issues, but asking for "any other software, architecture or whatever" to address three issues (and also to offer "similar functionality") makes this too broad.  It is simply inviting a series of answers like "You could try X", "You could try Y", "I think it does work with WFS", "I think it does work with MULTIGEOMETRIES", etc.